# Request for projects only with clients does not filter out projects without client

Tags: clockify

I use Postman to learn how to use API and i was trying to get list of projects only with clients. I tried make request with "archived: true" and it did work. But, when i try to use "contains-client: true", i get all projects, with and without client.